# How can I share data between child and parent (following fork()) in Linux?

Tags: c, fork, multiprocess

How can I share data between child and parent in Linux (not Windows)?

Source files:

1.h

```
extern int a;
extern int b;
```

2.h

```
#include "1.h"

void adder();
```

2.c

```
#include "2.h"

void adder()
{
    a++;
    b++;
}
```

1.c

```
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"

int a = 0;
int b = 0;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    while (1) {
        if (pid == 0) {
            adder();
        }
        printf("a: %d , b: %d\n", a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

result

```
a: 0  b: 0
```

How can I share the values of `a` and `b`? I want to get the result that `a` and `b` are increasing.

Comment: There are many ways to handle [inter-process communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), if you want to share memory then [*shared memory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29) seem to be a good thing to look at.

Comment: `fork()` creates a full copy of your virtual memory, commonly using copy-on-write. Global variables are private to the process. If they *weren't*, non-atomic non-readonly access without synchronisation would be undefined beeahviour.

Comment: This one line you show is all the output you get?

Comment: `This question already has an answer here:` in WinAPI!!! Good joke.